# How do I create a user invitation model?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am developing an application which allows 'users' to create 'lists'. I have a many-to-many relationship between 'users' and 'lists' (this might not be right). Additionally 'Lists' have many 'Tasks'.

What I would like to do is extend this model to include the idea of 'invitations'. I would like users to be able to invite one another to other lists. A user can create many invitations. A user can create an 'invitation' and the invitation would have one or many 'invitees' which, in turn, would be 'Users'. So am confused about how this should be organized in a relational db.

I think the core problem is: users 'own' invitations but also can be the recipient of an invitation. Clear as mud? :)

I was hoping someone could offer some advice on how this might be accomplished. Any example ERDs would be useful. If my question requires further clarification I can provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i will recapitulate your description:

- A user can create lists.
- A list tackles some tasks.
- Users can join some lists.
- A user can send an invitation to some users and propose to join some lists

Based on this description I would propose the following ERD

[image: ERD]

From this I would deduce the following relations

```
user('user_id')
list('list_id',user_id(creates))
joins('list_id','user_id')
task('list_id','task_id')
invitation('invitation_id',user_id(sends))
receives('invitation_id','user_id')
proposes('invitation_id','list_id')
```

Primary keys are between apostrophes. Foreign keys can be deduced by the names if the fields (so user_id in lists references user_id in user) The word in parantheses after a foreign_key describes from which relation in the ERD this foreign key is derrived.

I did not care abou the names of the id-columns. Perhaps an id is a surogate key (an artificial key) or  some attribue of the entity. also i did not add additional attributes which can be easily  added. The characterisation o task as a weak entity is rather arbitrary.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the diagram it really helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a pretty simple schema for this with a "trick": treat all `user -> list` associations as "invitations", including the ownership relation.

You'd have one table for the users (with say a `userid` column).
Then a table for the lists (with a `listid`).
The relation between the users and lists tables could be:

```
userid | listid    | role
----------------------------
bob    | dbas      | owner
alice  | dbas      | invitee
alice  | sysadmins | owner
bob    | sysadmins | invitee
eve    | sysadmins | invitee
```

An invitation is simply another line in that table.
This allows you to have different levels of access to the lists. A user could "invite" another to have full-control of a list, just read access, or something in between - just define the appropriate set of roles for your use-case.

You might want to add things like "creator" information, last modification information to the lists themselves.

Comment: squeezing all user list relations in one table seems not to be a good idea to me. You are ignoring all relational design principles (normal forms)

Comment: I'm not "squeezing all the list relations in one table", I'm creating a table for the one (and only) relation I'm considering (which is "user has access to list" essentially).

Comment: From  your statement 'treat all user -> list associations as "invitations"' I concluded that you want to store all user-list relations in one table. I see now that you do not put the 'creator' information in the invitation table (using a "createor" role). It is possible to merge some tables respresenting the relations between two entities into one table that contains a third column that holds a value to discriminate the relations. In contrast to my former statement I think this will not conflict to some normal forms. Nevertheless I do not like such an approach.